# scala json validation not working

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework-2.0

I am following **Play For Scala ** for validation and parsing of Json

I am receiving a request in controller after converting it to JsValue like this

```
 val jsonRequest = request.body.asJson.get
```

i am trying to validate it like this

```
jsonRequest.validate[ReadArtWorkCaseClass].fold(

valid = {    
          readArtWorkCaseClass =>
            log.info("valid block")

          Ok("validation successful" )
         },     
invalid = {
           log.info("invalid block")
           errors => {               
             log.info("error block")
             BadRequest(JsError.toFlatJson(errors))
            }           
          }                    
        )
```

i have implemented Read for this

```
case class ReadArtWorkCaseClass(artworkid :String,
                                artistid :String,
                                institutionid :String ,
                                status :String,
                                groupactivityid:String,
                                details:String,
                                pricehistoryid :String,
                                sku :String,
                                dimensions :String,
                                artworkname :String,
                                artworkseries :String ,
                                workclassifier :String ,
                                genreid :String,
                                artworktype :String,
                                createddate:String)
    object ReadArtWorkCaseClass {

   implicit val artworkReads: Reads[ReadArtWorkCaseClass] = (
(JsPath \ "artWorkid").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "artistid").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "institutionid").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "activationStatus").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "groupactivityid").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "details").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "pricehistoryid").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "sku").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "dimensions").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "artworkname").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "artworkseries").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "workclassifier").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "genreid").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "artworktype").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "createddate").read[String]
)(ReadArtWorkCaseClass.apply _)
}
```

when i tried to validate jsonrequest by inputing empty fields it does not go into the invalid block instead runs the valid block

please guide me what is my mistake

Comment: What do you mean by 'empty fields'? If you're putting empty strings as values it is correct. An empty string is still a string.  You should paste a sample of your test data.

Comment: i am submitting form with empty fileds

i think you are right  but when i try to specify the length of a particular string like this

(JsPath \ "artWorkid").read[String](minLength[String](10))

it gives me following error

method minLength: (length: Int)play.api.data.validation.Constraint[String] does not take 
 type parameters.

Comment: Based on the error message I would try `minLength(10)` instead.  It looks like the type parameter is already set to `String` and you don't need to specify it when calling the function.

Comment: i have tried it like this (JsPath \ "artWorkid").read[String](minLength(10)) but it gives error on this part  "(JsPath \ "artWorkid").read[String]" and the error is    "overloaded method value read with alternatives: (t: String)play.api.libs.json.Reads[String] <and> 
 (implicit r: play.api.libs.json.Reads[String])play.api.libs.json.Reads[String] cannot be applied to 
 (play.api.data.validation.Constraint[String])"    , is there some import that i am missing or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(JsPath \ "artWorkid").read(minLength[String](1))
```

it worked for me